# ZXing to verify a text form barcode reader

Tags: c#, zxing

The question is simple. Is it possible to use ZXing C# library to veryify a barcode entered manually form a user ? We need this because sometimes happens that the barcodes are corrupt and the operator must insert the underlying numbers by hand. The barcode format is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

On my code I use the following to generate an image from the code entered by a user:

```
        var writer = new BarcodeWriter();
        writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
        var options = new EncodingOptions();
        options.Height = 140;
        options.Width = 300;
        writer.Options = options;

        try
        {
            Bitmap image = writer.Write(textBoxCodigoDeBarras.Text);
            BitmapImage bi = ImageManager.BitmapToImagesource(image);
            ImageCodigoDeBarras.Source = bi;
        }
        catch
        {
            //Could not generate image.
            //Therefone Barcode is invalid.
        }
```

Comment: Interesting !!!  I think that there should be into their code a direct method useful in these cases !! But this workaround is good too

Comment: Another reason is that I cannot know the barcode FORMAT previously !!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to validate something you don't know what it is. Wouldn't be possible to add a combo-box where the user must select the type of bar-code? Or, select the type of bar-code based on the type or origin of the product/box that the user is keying into the system?

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmmmm no ! The barcode reader used , reads many barcodes types so its' impossibile. Maybe I'll use your answer cycling through all possibible barcodes